# Jump to next iteration of outer loop

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, loops, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following code:

```
quantity.times do
  ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
    #a bunch of nested if/thens
    if index == 0
      do something else
      send termination email
    end
  end
end
```

Basically, if the termination email is sent, I only want it sent ONCE regardless how many items are in the `ids` array. Once this is sent, I want to go tot he next number in the `quantity times` loop. Of course, if the termination email is not sent and the other actions are executed, then it's fine to continue looping through the `ids` array.

What I have now works, because I'm using the `index==0` to only trigger the email once, but I'd like to streamline further.

I know about the `next` method [1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby/ruby_loops.htm), but I understand that jumps to the next iteration of the inner loop, in this case the `ids.each` loop, which isn't what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may be a bit redundant, but to better understand your question, I did:

```
quantity = 2
ids = ["a", "b"]

quantity.times do
  puts "outer loop"
  ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
    puts "inner loop"
    # a bunch of nested if/thens
    if index == 0
      puts "do something else"
      puts "send termination email"
      break
    end
  end
end
```

The output was:

```
outer loop
inner loop
do something else
send termination email
outer loop
inner loop
do something else
send termination email
```

if I take out the break, the output changes to:

```
outer loop
inner loop
do something else
send termination email
inner loop
outer loop
inner loop
do something else
send termination email
inner loop
```

This effectively saves a few inner loop iterations.  Is this what your are looking for?

Comment: Yes! That is great I had thought to try to use break to remove the index, but per my commentary above I see why it's critical. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Probably you are looking for the **break** keyword.

```
for i in 0..5
   if i > 2 then
      break
   end
   puts "Value of local variable is #{i}"
end
```

This will produce the following result:

```
Value of local variable is 0
Value of local variable is 1
Value of local variable is 2
```

Answer (score 1):

```
quantity.times do
  ids.each_with_index do |id, index|
    #a bunch of nested if/thens
      break if send termination email
  end
end
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Sorry for being dense, it's probably too late to be working... but anyways, how would it work if i needed to do somethign else and then send the termination email and then break? I tried to write the code like this: 1) `final if/then statement evaluates to true`, 2) `do something else`, 3) `send termination email`, 4) `break`. But this broke all my tests...

Comment: Oh actually I know what the problem is. The problem is the placement of the `break`. With the `index == 0`, I could ensure that the entire block of code within the `if` statement only happened once. Any idea how to resolve? I almost want like a `break after ... end`

Comment: My code does exactly what you want. A bunch of code before `break` is being executed, then we try to send an email and break the loop if and only it was sent successfully. Am I misunderstood you?

Comment: Yeah it wasn't explained super well. Basically I only want to "do something else" on the iteration that needs the termination email, not the ones thereafter. Which is why it's still important to wrap the break in the `index` loop